# Storing a 3D point array representing a flight path?

Tags: postgresql, spatial, postgis, array

I need to store an array of 3D points in a column: latitude, longitude, altitude

What datatype would be required for this?

Also, if I wanted to extend this in the future to include time (ie an array of 4D points), how could I do so?

I have gone for a custom datatype, but I am not sure if this is wise:

```
CREATE TYPE position3d AS (f1 DOUBLE PRECISION, f2 DOUBLE PRECISION, f3 DOUBLE PRECISION)
```

I then created a new column with type `position3d[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly geospatial. My advice to you is to install [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/). Store them as a point. Points can have z-cordinates. Creating a custom type is a bad idea.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  geog geography(POINT),
  alt  int
);

INSERT INTO foo(geog,alt) VALUES
  (ST_MakePoint(long,lat), alt);
```

If you want to extend to include time, just add a timestamp column.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say *"an array of 3D points"*, but typically that either means you need to normalize into a point table, or store a `MULTIPOINT`, or by array you mean `LINESTRING`.

## Flight path

If you're trying to store a flight path you want a `LINESTRING` you can create one with [`ST_MakeLine`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html).

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id   serial                  PRIMARY KEY,
  path geography(LINESTRINGZ)
);
INSERT INTO foo(path) VALUES
  (
    ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[
      ST_MakePoint(1,2,3),
      ST_MakePoint(5,5,4),
      ST_MakePoint(10,10,5)
    ])
  );

# SELECT id, ST_AsText(path) FROM foo;
 id |             st_astext              
----+------------------------------------
  1 | LINESTRING Z (1 2 3,5 5 4,10 10 5)
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "an array of 3D points": I want to have a column with a collection of double precisions, representing latitude, longitude and altitude

Comment: @pookie what does the collection represent in the real world?

Comment: a trajectory such as the flight route of an airplane

Comment: @pookie so that's not a collection, or an array. That's a LINESTRING. It's a sequence of points captured in time representing the movement of an object in space. That's what they're there for.

Comment: @pookie updated.

Comment: Great, thanks. I had no idea there is a LINESTRING type.